# iOS 8.3 and html5 <picture>

Tags: html, image, ios8.3

I have a question regarding old version of iOS (especially 8.3) and html5 tag `<picture>`. I cannot use it for old iOS devices.

Do I have any chance to trick iOS or is it possible to have some hooks to make it work properly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not mind a javascript solution, Picturefill will enable support for the `<picture>` tag in browsers that do not support it. I have used it myself for various projects in the past, and it is a drag and drop solution that works without issue.

https://scottjehl.github.io/picturefill/